# How do I create blurry effects with GIMP

Tags: linux, images, opensuse, gimp

I am new to gimp and I have no clue if this is the right place to ask, so bear with me and steer me in the correct direction if i am  wrong in asking this.

How do I create blurry visual effects?

I want to take and manipulate some images of books for a website.  I am starting with this image.
[image: see the image here]

I would love to be able to make it look more like [what you see here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/azrasta/5088254388/in/faves-38172986@N05/).  Is this possible with GIMP?  How would I go about it?

I considered asking you for other opinions, other suggestions as to different effects I could apply to the image to make it look more original, but I realized that this was going outside of the scope of solving problems.

[Here are more](http://www.flickr.com/photos/38172986@N05/8644303439/in/set-72157633235647884/) of my very basic approaches in getting some better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you are trying to archive is called "bokeh", and its archived by dslr mirror cameras for parts of the scene that lie outside the depth of field.

I've only ever used photoshop so I cannot tell you the specifics for gimps but, the first thing you should do is select what you don't want blurred and place it on a different layer, then apply some sort of filder to blur out the background. I do not think gimp has a depth of field blur filter, so using a gaussian blurr will not give you a 'real' bokeh effect, but it'll be close enough.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nn2q1U1yGQ) tutorial will show you step by step how to do it. Also btw, this question should probably be moved to [graphical design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: looks kind of like solarisation to me

Comment: the image he showed also has some kind of tint or color grading effect, but thats a different story

Comment: Hello you both - mille gracie - thx for all the help. Will work on. And btw. further questions are directed to the graphical-design board. Thx alot